# Determine Object type with polymorphic calls

Tags: java, class, oop, polymorphism

Instead of using `instanceof` (which I've heard is a bad habit) i want to determine an object's type with polymorphic calls. 
For instance, i have a super class `A` (abstract) and two subclasses of `A`: `B` and `C`.
I i also have an `ArrayList<A>` in `A` containing instances of both `B` and `C`. I want to count every instance of `B` in the ArrayList. When iterating through the `ArrayList` present in `A`, how can i know if the present element in the iteration of the array is of type `B` or type `C`?

Comment: "poliphormic"?  Seriously though this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) type question. Better to tell the overall behavior that you're trying to elicit than how you're trying to elicit it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels polymorphic! wow that's a stupid mistake.

Comment: See edits to comment (refresh the page). Tell more concrete details of what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to do it.

Comment: Please post code so that we could be of better help. You can always compare class objects `if ( list.get(i).getClass().equals( B.class ) ){..}`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i tried asking it differently, how's that?

Comment: No,  you're asking it wrong, and it's still an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question (please click on the link). The best solution is to not do an instanceof or similar check. Perhaps you need to use a Visitor Design Pattern to emulate double-dispatch, but as asked it's currently impossible to tell. Again, please make your question much more informative and concrete.

Comment: @aomin: yep, that's exactly what Jon Skeet recommended in the dup you posted -- *consider* visitor pattern as a double-dispatch. Or just use instanceof.